# React proxy not conecting to api url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, proxy

when i am building a social media website, but i have run into a big problem, my api server runs on localhost:6000, and my react app runs on the default of localhost:3000, i have setup my proxy in the react app's package.json to the api url (localhost:6000), but when i make an api call using axios for example

```
const response = await axios.get("/api/users", body, config);
console.log(response.data);
```

the front end makes the api call to the localhost:300 url not my api url, 
please what can i do to fix this problem it has been bugging me for the past 2 days now lol.

Answer (score 1):

try setting "proxy": "127.0.0.1:6000" in your package.json file for your client.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions you could try and follow

`axios.get('http://localhost:6000/api/users')`

or have you tried adding this to the request?

```
headers: {
    "accepts":"application/json"
}
```

and finally you could try and use this package

`const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');`

Comment: ill checkout the package, and even if i use the full api url without the proxy it still sends me to localhost 3000

Comment: @DBankx have you rebooted both servers after adding the proxy?

Comment: i just found out it works, its just the console logs an error for some wierd reason

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:6000/api/users", body, config);
console.log(response.data);
```

Should work, or am I missing something?

Comment: it still sends me to port 3000